# Bootstrap popover keeps staying when clicking div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 popover when hovering a image a popover opens.
But when you click the zoom function inside the image the image opens up larger but the popover is not closing instead it does not close anymore.

Here is the website where the bug happens;
https://www.vanderdrift.bvdodev.nl/nl/creeer-jouw-eigen-tafel

Hover over image right to see the popover and then click the 'zoom' function to see the bug.

I tried fixing it with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.configurator-zoom').click(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover focus" });
    });
});
```

But the popover is still not closing.
Can someone please take a look?

Thanks!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing it with this script: `toggleEnabled`
That makes toggle the popover.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.configurator-zoom').click(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover,focus" });
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggleEnabled');
    });
});
```

More info : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/